# Usage of javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX results in blank page after long load

Tags: jsf-2, web.xml, jsf-2.2

With my files named to `.xhtml` and no redefinition  of `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` in my web.xml, everything works properly.

But I would like to use the `.html` extension as I write html5 and not xhtml.

Here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.html</param-value>
</context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I visit  `contextname/` I would expect to fall on the same page than `contextname/index.jsf` as it is the first of my welcome file list but instead index.html file is used and I see the template code, as I would expect by visiting `contextname/index.html`.

When I try to visit `contextname/index.jsf` there is a very long load, around 10 seconds and the page ends up blank.

Once again, without the parameter and with my file renamed to `index.xhtml` everything works fine.

Comment: *"But I would like to use the .html extension as I write html5 and not xhtml."* This is really beyond me. It seems that you completely missed the point of XHTML. Carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info then. Coming back to the concrete question, what exactly do you ultimately want to see in browser's address bar URL? If I guess right, you rather want `http://example.com/contextname/index.html` instead of `http://example.com/contextname/index.jsf`, right?

Comment: Thanks for the refresh about XHTML. My question is about the backend, I wanted to write my templates in .html files, no matter what appears in the browser's url. I think could achieve what you talk about with `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` but it is not my point here. Thing is I want to access the content of `index.html` at the address `index.jsf`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But it is not an issue as I know now that it is true that html5 is xhtml when used approprietly. I would like to find the bug for the sake of it but I will use xhtml extension in the end.

Comment: Hm, just get rid of `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>`?

Comment: Same result. May be a bug in Tomcat 8 or in a lib I use somewhere. I'll update the content of my web.xml to show you.